# How to solve "variable is not accessed" error in VS? -python-

Tags: python, rasa

this is my python code and as you can see the variable `choics` that I'm trying to define and give some value keeps showing an error "is not accessed Pylance" in VS,

the error is in this line:         `choice = tracker.get_slot("customer_choice")`

and this is the code:

```
from typing import Any, Text, Dict, List


from rasa_sdk import Action, Tracker
from rasa_sdk.executor import CollectingDispatcher



class ActionConfirmOrder(Action):

    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "action_confirm_order"

    cus_choice = "pizza"

    def run(self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
            tracker: Tracker,
            domain: Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:

        choice = tracker.get_slot("customer_choice")
        dispatcher.utter_message(text="Your order is {choice}\n it will be ready within 10min")
        

        return []
```

*I'm using the code in the file **actions.py** in `RASA` demo files in case you know anything about `RASA`*

so if anyone knows what is the problem and can help me. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a standard linter error letting you know that you've declared a variable without using it -- sometimes it indicates a typo in your code, or an opportunity to clean up dead code.

If you see this error and you *think* you *are* using the variable, look very carefully at the line of code where you're using it, and you'll probably find a subtle problem around scoping, or a typo in the variable name, or something like that.

In this case, the typo is that your f-string is missing its `f`.

```
dispatcher.utter_message(text="Your order is {choice}\n it will be ready within 10min")
```

Change `text="Your order is {choice}..."` to `text=f"Your order is {choice}..."` so that `choice` will get used in generating the string.  Without the `f` before the string, `{choice}` will be rendered as literally `"{choice}"` and your `choice` value doesn't get used for anything.